# 3 tables joins performance issue

Tags: postgresql, join, performance, postgresql-performance

DB: Postgres 9.4

schema:

```
table a:
id, score

table ab:
a_id, b_id, b_type

table b:
id, name, type
```

I am trying to get top 10 result in the following format:

```
name, count(group by name), average(score)
```

`count` is the total occurrences of `a` group by `name`

Basically I can do a 3 table join:

```
select name, count(*), average(score)
from a
joins ab
on a.id = ab.a_id
joins b
on b.id = ab.b_id
where type = 'sometype'
group by name
order by count(*) desc limit 10
```

This works, but the performance is very slow since my middle table ab is like 200M record, and the index is pretty large as well.

Fortunately I can filter on the table ab and make the result to around 1000 rows.

```
select filtered_ab.b_id, count(1) as ct
from (
  select b_id
  from ab
  where b_type = 'sometype'
) as filtered_ab
group by filtered_ab.b_id
order by ct desc limit 1000
```

This will give me the top 1000 `b_id`s.

Now I only have to joins table b with this result to append name column to it.

```
select name, b_id, ct
from b
join (
select filtered_ab.b_id, count(1) as ct
from (
  select b_id
  from ab
  where b_type = 'sometype'
) as filtered_ab
group by filtered_ab.b_id
order by ct desc limit 1000
) as b_with_counts
on b_with_counts.b_id = b.id
```

I am returning top 1000 is because currently `name` and `b.id` is not 1 to 1, same `name` can have like 1 to 5 `b.id`s, so just return 1000, and then group by `name` later to approximately get all the counts for the same `name`.

But after this, I cannot figure out a way to append the average score from table a.

Currently the data in table ab, for each `b_id`, there can be 1 to 1000000 or more `a_id`s.

Comment: Table definitions should show data types and constraints - what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Please also add relevant indexes and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for performance questions. You did not define `top 10 results` - the ones with the highest count? How to break ties? [Please consider instructions in the tag info for \[postgresql-performance\].](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). I remember suggesting this to you before.